# What to include in Metal shader

Tags: ios, xcode, metal

I'm new to Metal. In some example shaders, I see

```
#include <simd/simd.h>
```

In others, I see

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
```

The shader with `metal_stdlib` compiles in an example Xcode project which I found on the web. But it does not compile if I include it in my existing project where I get the error message `'metal_stdlib' file not found`. (the one with `simd/simd.h` works fine).

I'm confused as to what is going on. Maybe this is due to a different Metal version? I've been trying to find where there is a difference in the Xcode settings between the two projects (of which there are thousands), but no luck yet. When does one include `<simd/simd.h>`, when `<metal_stdlib>`?

--
**Update:**

The compilation fails in an Objective-C file where I included the shared header (which includes the `#include <metal_stdlib>`). Still very confused.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this for a bit as well, all to realize I actually had mistakenly imported my metal file in an Obj-C source code file. No metal header files may be imported on any other header or source code files.

`Simd.h` provides small vector (simd) and matrix types, as well as basic arithmetic and mathematical functions for them.

On the other hand, `metal_stdlib` provides the foundation platform-dependent header libraries for the metal framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `#include <metal_stdlib>` in the shared header because it relates only to the Metal Shading Language. It should be moved to the shader implementation `.metal` file.